# Rotate function

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

Why isn't this working? I need it for a school project. It should be simple.

```
var Rotate = function(d){
  $(".fab").css({
      '-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */',
      'transition-duration: 1s;',
      '-moz-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-o-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-ms-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
   });
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: please mention the problem you are facing..

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The one problem that I see is with `'transition-duration: 1s;',` instead of `'transition-duration': 1s,` and similarily in this `'-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */'`

Comment: The function just doensn't work. Without '-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */','transition-duration: 1s;', it works perfect

Comment: It turns but not with a time

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AKS's answer has what's wrong with your syntax, but the way you're attempting to use the transition property is incorrect. You need to have the transition defined first, and then perform some css change to trigger the transition. From what you've shown us, you have the trigger part only.

Some basic CSS you could use is

```
.fab {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

And your JavaScript becomes

```
var Rotate = function(d){
    $(".fab").css({
        '-moz-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
        '-o-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
        '-ms-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
    });
}
```

Note that this will perform the transition for any property that can use a transition, so you may want to be more specific using `transition: transform 1s;` as your CSS instead.

You can read up about transitions more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). Also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gpoe0z3/) is a working fiddle

Comment: @LaurentS if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Rotate = function(d){
  $(".fab").css({
      '-webkit-transition-duration': 1s,
      'transition-duration': 1s,
      '-moz-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-o-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      '-ms-transform':'rotate('+d+'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate('+d+'deg)'
   });
}
```

So were using a string

```
'-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */',
'transition-duration: 1s;',
```

instead use key value pair like you used for `transform` or `rotate`:

```
'-webkit-transition-duration': 1s,
'transition-duration': 1s,
```